# Javascript Convert 'List()' to list

Tags: javascript

I received data from another API. But I don't know how to convert and use data.

data example

```
{
   ...
   answer:'List(value1,value2,value3,value4)',
   ...
}
```

I want to iterate all answer nodes. please help.

Comment: What is a `List`? Right now you have a string

Comment: I don't know that either

Comment: please provide ample sample data to work with

Comment: Put some real value of **answer** property so that it will be easy to understand your problem.

Comment: If YOU don't know, how can we know? ;)

Comment: value is just url string like this > answer:'List(http://www.google.com/image.png,http://www.google.com/result.png)'

Comment: use this : `response.answer.substring(5,response.answer.length-1).split(',')`

Comment: I didn't know what a List is, so I asked if there was a way to use it.

Comment: Why would any API return non standard non neutral formats instead of a string array? If this is an internal API, I recommend to fix the output.

Answer (score 4):

#### Approach

You could capture the group between `List(...)` and split that by comma `,`

Regex test: https://regex101.com/r/xFf39R/1

```js
const answer = 'List(value1,value2,value3,value4)'

const res = /List\((.*)\)/.exec(answer)[1].split(',')

console.log(res)
```

---

#### Reference

[RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

> **Return value**
>
> [...] The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each parenthetical capture group of the matched text.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your data example... It seems like the answer is carrying a String as the single quote is presented in your data example.

```
answer:'List(value1,value2,value3,value4)'
       ^                                 ^
```

And the `List(value1,value2,value3,value4)` actually looks like some python List in system print.
Well, but this does not help in your direct question.

Assuming your want to get all four values into an array in javascript, do the followings

```
let data_example = {
   ...
   'answer':'List(value1,value2,value3,value4)',
   ...
}
let answer_string = data_example['answer'].slice(5,-1)
let your_list = answer_string.split(',')
console.log(your_list)
//["value1","value2","value3","value4"]
```

But be careful... I assume your List() always start with 'List(' and end with ')'
See more on [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)